# Keycloak - "Level Of Authentication" (LoA) maxAge in access token

Tags: keycloak, multi-factor-authentication

I'm using an authentication flow with keycloak's `Condition - Level Of Authentication` execution to implement steo-up authentication. Everything works as expected.

But I'd like the `Max Age` parameter to be written into the access token, so that I can inspect the validity of the token and make an educated decision whether or not to ask the user for a new authentication.

I've already tried adding the built-in ACR token mapper, but without success. I also checked, whether the `exp` property of the jwt is altered to reflect the validity of the second factor, but it is not.

Is there a way to get the maxAge of the LoA into the access token? If not, is there another way of knowing whether the second factor is exprired, without triggering a new Login?

I'm using keycloak 18

Comment: Hello, having the same issue did you come up with a solution since ?

Comment: @sashok_bg no, unfortunately not. we now just check the `auth_time` field in the token and compare it with a hardcoded maxAge property which is the same as the value configured in keycloak :-/